# How to flatten list in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where one column RESULT has list inside a list.

```
  ID                     RESULT
0  A  [nan, ['PASS'], nan, nan]
1  B  [['FAIL'], nan, nan, nan]
2  C  [['PASS'], nan, nan, nan]
3  D       [nan, nan, nan, nan]
4  E  [nan, ['FAIL'], nan, nan]
```

I want to make the RESULT column a flat list. For example the first case would be [nan, 'PASS', nan, nan]. Final answer should look like below.

```
  ID                     RESULT
0  A  [nan, 'PASS', nan, nan]
1  B  ['FAIL', nan, nan, nan]
2  C  ['PASS', nan, nan, nan]
3  D  [nan, nan, nan, nan]
4  E  [nan, 'FAIL', nan, nan]
```

I tried to create a function but it is not updating the column to a flat list. Below is the code I tried.

```
def flatten_list(mylist):
    # print(mylist)
    for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
        if type(value) is list:
            mylist[index] = value[0]
        # print(mylist)
        return mylist

df_bin['RESULT'] = df_bin['RESULT'].apply(flatten_list)
```

But if I try a simple example below it works. I wonder what is the difference. I will appreciate any guidance. Also is it possible to use lambda function to achieve the same result.

```
mylist = [nan, ['PASS'], nan, nan]
for n, i in enumerate(mylist):
    if type(i) is list:
        mylist[n] = i[0]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do this using an internal `flatten` function from `pandas.core`

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.common import flatten

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B'],
                   'Result':[['nan', ['PASS'], 'nan', 'nan'], [['FAIL'], 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']]
                  })
df['Result'] = df['Result'].apply(lambda x: list(flatten(x)))
```

Output:

```
    ID  Result
0   A   [nan, PASS, nan, nan]
1   B   [FAIL, nan, nan, nan]
```

Based on your example, I guess this should work.

Comment: It is changing column as below. Is it because in your dataframe 'nan' is a string and the one I am using it is nan (Not a Number)?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ID                                             RESULT
0   A  [[, n, a, n, ,,  , [, ', P, A, S, S, ', ], ,, ...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a dataframe creator (based on the data you have)? I am not sure why nan will be split in your case if it is a number.

Comment: I just tested with np.nan the results are same. I think this is because your dataframe column is not a list but a string of list.

Comment: OK I can confirm the behaviour you mentioned happens if your column value is a string of list and not just list as you mentioned in the question. You can confirm by checking type(df.loc[0,'Result']). Now if that is the case, there are a few ways such as using numpy or literal_eval to extract list from the string. Please share more information.

Comment: DrSpill, you are correct. it is a string. The original dataframe had some empty rows in the RESULT column. Then I used group by command below and as a result RESULT column changed to string with empty column values replaced by nan, concatenated with the [PASS] or [FAIL] list. Thanks for checking. I will rephrase my question to indicate that.                                                                                                                     df = df.groupby('ID').aggregate(lambda tdf: tdf.tolist())

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you have to unindent the return statement

```
def flatten_list(mylist):
    # print(mylist)
    for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
        if type(value) is list:
            mylist[index] = value[0]
        # print(mylist)
        return mylist  # <- indentation issue here.
```

Here is a more general solution if your sublist contains more than one item.

```
def flatten_list(cell):
  fcell = []
  for item in cell:
    if isinstance(item, list):
      fcell += item
    else:
      fcell += [item]
  return fcell


df_bin['RESULT'] =  df_bin['RESULT'].apply(flatten_list)
```

[demo](https://repl.it/@riless/64628230)

Comment: Original Dataframe
ID                     RESULT
0  A  [nan, ['PASS'], nan, nan]
1  B  [['FAIL'], nan, nan, nan]
2  C  [['PASS'], nan, nan, nan]
3  D       [nan, nan, nan, nan]


After applying flatten_list function on RESULT column it is separating each character as a list element.
   ID                                             RESULT
0   A  [[, n, a, n, ,,  , [, ', P, A, S, S, ', ], ,, ...
1   B  [[, [, ', F, A, I, L, ', ], ,,  , n, a, n, ,, ...
2   C  [[, [, ', P, A, S, S, ', ], ,,  , n, a, n, ,, ...
3   D  [[, n, a, n, ,,  , n, a, n, ,,  , n, a, n, ,, ...

Comment: check [this link](https://repl.it/@riless/64628230) for a runnable demo.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way of doing this (if you care about performance) is avoiding a loop and using numpy.hstack instead. Here is an example.

```
from numpy import hstack, nan
lst= [nan, ['PASS'], nan, nan]

lst2 = list(hstack(lst))

print(lst2)
```

Output:

```
['nan', 'PASS', 'nan', 'nan']
```